# Editors see each others items in Workbox

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-workflow

Right now all editors see each others items in draft state and can cross-submit those.

Is it possible to manage that editors with the same access rights see in the workbox only their items they have submitted?

Answer (score 1):

**Advanced Workbox** module in market place has "**My Items**" filter which will show user specific items.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Advanced_Workbox.aspx

This module works similar to the workbox and has additional filters.

You can extend this module to display user specific items by default to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, i don't think that is possible in Sitecore, I suggest you create different roles for editors and assign security permissions accordingly, and have each role to have access to one state in your Workflow.

You could extend Workflow application yourself, but that will require some work/time to complete.

**EDIT**

I found an [article](https://adeneys.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/get-your-workflow-in-order/) that explains how to extend workflow box, it only reorder the items, but it can be changed to apply your requirement, you just need to alter GetItems() method to return items that current user submitted

I think the example in this article will help you achieve this.

Comment: Thanks. Our company requires to have more content editors with the same access rights as the website is too large. Splitting the content into multiple sections and restrict those via user roles (with different access rights) is unfortunatelly not an option in this case. I guess extending the WF app itself will be necessary as you have suggested. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: I have extended workbox before, not for the same requirements as yours, but i guess it could help you get started, let me know if you need some examples

Comment: Sure, any examples could be useful as there is a pressure on this issue to be solved asap :) I would definitely appreciate some.

Comment: @MartinD I have updated my answer with article that explain how to extend workflow box, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will let you know how did it go.